# Ubuntu 18.04 on Gigabyte UEFI Motherboard not seeing all CPU cores

Tags: uefi, cpu

My system is only recognizing 1 CPU core, and 1 thread (I also had many problems even getting Ubuntu to load without multiple stalls). The OS is running horrible under any load.

```
Here are the system specs:

OS: Ubuntu 19.04
Motherboard: Gigabyte Z390 AORUS PRO WIFI
RAM: 16GB
Storage: ATA Samsung SSD 860; ATA WDC WD10EZEX

$ sudo lshw -C cpu 
  *-cpu                     
       description: CPU
       product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700K CPU @ 3.70GHz
       vendor: Intel Corp.
       physical id: 47
       bus info: cpu@0
       version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700K CPU @ 3.70GHz
       serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       slot: U3E1
       size: 3783MHz
       capacity: 4700MHz
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 100MHz
       capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
       configuration: cores=6 enabledcores=6 threads=12

$ sudo lshw -C memory
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: F10
       date: 06/05/2019
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 15MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 3a
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-2400C15-4GVR
          vendor: Fujitsu
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-2400C15-4GVR
          vendor: Fujitsu
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-2400C15-4GVR
          vendor: Fujitsu
          physical id: 2
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-2400C15-4GVR
          vendor: Fujitsu
          physical id: 3
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 44
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 45
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 1536KiB
       capacity: 1536KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 46
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 12MiB
       capacity: 12MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: RAM memory
       product: Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:5123a000-5123bfff memory:51240000-51240fff
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97794/discussion-on-question-by-rik-wadge-ubuntu-18-04-on-gigabyte-uefi-motherboard-no).

Comment: See http://forum.gigabyte.us/thread/7085/aorus-windows-ubuntu-install-issues

Answer (score 1):

**Check your current BIOS version**. In `terminal` do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. If it's not version F10 from 6/27/2019, then go to https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/Z390-AORUS-PRO-WIFI-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios to get the latest version, and install it.

*Note: you may need to reset the BIOS to factory defaults for the motherboard to see all of your cores.*

**Update #1:**

- updated the BIOS from F7 to F10. Did not fix the problem.
- `sudo lshw -C cpu` shows it sees all 6 cores.
- doesn't boot from a 19.04 Ubuntu Live DVD either.
- http://forum.gigabyte.us/thread/7085/aorus-windows-ubuntu-install-issues indicates that Ubuntu may not work on this motherboard.